# Getting Location in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

In the new Windows 10 documentation, it says that before getting a user's location that you should use Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync().  However, the method doesn't seem to be available.  The only options I can use are are "Geolocator.Equals" and "Geolocator.ReferenceEqual".

When I try to get the location without using the RequestAccessAsync.  I get an error saying the "pipe is being closed".  I've included the code that I'm trying to use to get the location below.

```
Geolocator geolocator1 = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 250 };
Geoposition pos = await geolocator1.GetGeopositionAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was caused by me trying to do this in a Class Library that was targeting Windows 8.1 instead of Windows 10.  Changing it, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have the right project type? The Geolocator for Windows 8.1 apps does not have this method, but it does have the other methods and properties you call in your code snippet.

[Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.requestaccessasync.aspx)() should be available for Universal Windows apps and shows up for me in a Windows Universal project in Visual Studio 2015RC.

It is a static function so you don't need an instance of an object:

```
await Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also need to check if the following is set in the  section of the Package.appxmanifest:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="location" />
```

You can check out my own [Location Example](https://github.com/RoguePlanetoid/Windows-10-Universal-Windows-Platform-Tutorials/tree/master/Location) if this helps too